# можно ли в phpStorm сделать подсказки более структурированными?

Tags: phpstorm

создаю type, навожу мышку на название, получаю подсказку о типе:

```
Initial type: {setBrand: (car: Car, value: Car["brand"]) => void, setModel: (car: Car,
               value: Car["model"]) => void, setYear: (car: Car, value: Car["year"]) => 
              void}
```

то есть сплошным текстом без структуры. можно ли сделать подсказку, как в Visual Studio Code структурированной? типа

```
Initial type: {
               setBrand: (car: Car, value: Car["brand"]) => void,
               setModel: (car: Car, value: Car["model"]) => void,
               setYear: (car: Car, value: Car["year"]) => void
              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну, раз никто не знает — я скажу.
если зажать ctrl, и навести на тип — то подсказка получается гораздо более структурированной.